# Return true or false as custom column based on condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

This might be very simple to achieve but I have not done this before and I need some guide or help in achieving this.

I have created a stored procedure and passing the UserId to the procedure. I have to modify my query and want a custom column to be returned in the query which will be either true' or 'false'. True or false will be determined whether User has commented for the Post or not. The pseudo code of the desired query is as follows,

```
SELECT 
    a.Id, 
    a.Title, 
    a.Description, 
    b.Id, 
    b.Comment, 
    ['true' or 'false' as Commented based on whether User has commented for the respective post or not] 
from tbl_Posts a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_PostsComment 
    b ON a.Id = b.PostId
```

**TABLES**

```
tbl_Users
---------------
Id
Username
FirstName
LastName
Address


tbl_Posts
---------------
Id
Title
Description


tbl_PostsComment
------------------
Id
PostId
UserId
Comment
```

Thanks

Edit:

To help better explain the question I will describe the scenario. In my website when the Users log in then they will see all posts and their comments. So records are selected using the query that I have posted above. Now their is a button with every post "Give comments". By clicking this user will be able to give the comments for any respective post but only if he has not already given the comments.

So what I want to do is to select all the records as usual but now I am passing the UserId to the stored procedure. All posts will be selected but if for any post User has already given comments (If Comments for that post will be present in the tbl_PostsComment with UserId of the User) then true will be returned otherwise false will be returned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this one will work:

```
SELECT
    a.Id,
    a.Title,
    a.Description,
    HasCommented = CASE WHEN COUNT(c.Id) > 0 THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END
FROM tbl_Posts p
LEFT JOIN tbl_postsComment c
    on c.PostId = p.Id
    AND c.UserId = @userId
GROUP BY
    a.Id, a.Title, a.Description
```

Comment: In your query the comments table is not present in the join. I will try to explain this question more. Kindly see edit in my question.

Comment: Isn't `tbl_PostsComment` the comments table?

Comment: My bad. Ye indeed it is. I just got it wrong. But still the query is not achieving what I desire. Kindly remember I passing the UserId to the stored procedure and UserId will be matched with it.

Comment: Just replace `b.UserId` with the `@userId` variable in your SP

Comment: I have achieved this by HasCommented = CASE WHEN b.UserId = @UserId THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
SELECT a.Title, a.Description, b.ID, b.Comment CASE WHEN b.Comment IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [Commented]
FROM tbl_Posts a LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_PostsComment b ON a.Id = b.PostId
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. This i snot exactly what I am looking for. In my application all posts will be selected for every user but if the user has commented on any post then true will be returned else false will be returned. I am sorry for not explaining my self clearly.